# How to stop over counting of duplicate letters in a list of strings

Tags: python, string, list

I'm trying to count the number of times a duplicate letter shows up in the list element.

For example, given

```
arr = ['capps','hat','haaah']
```

I out put a list and I get `['1','0','1']`

```
def myfunc(words):
    counter = 0 #counters dup letters in words
    len_ = len(words)-1
    for i in range(len_):
        if words[i] == words[i+1]: #if the letter ahead is the same add one
            counter+=1
    return counter

def minimalOperations(arr):
     return [*map(myfunc,arr)] #map fuc applies myfunc to element in words.
```

But my code would output [1,0,2]

I'm not sure why I am over counting.
Can anyone help me resolve this, thank you in advance.

Comment: 'haaah' has two duplicate letters. h(aa)ah and ha(aa)h.

Comment: when there two consecutive letters together that one. So "aa" is one "aaa" should be one as well

Answer (score 2):

A more efficient solution using a regular expression:

```
import re

def myfunc(words):
    reg_str = r"(\w)\1{1,}"
    return len(re.findall(reg_str, words))
```

This function will find the number of substrings of length 2 or more containing the same letter. Thus 'aaa' in your example will only be counted once.

For a string like

```
'hhhhfafaahggaa'
```

the output will be 4 , since there are 4 maximal substrings of the same letter occuring at least twice : 'hhh' , 'ss', 'gg', 'aa'

Answer (score 1):

You aren't accounting for situations where you have greater than 2 identical characters in succession. To do this, you can look back as well as forward:

```
if (words[i] == words[i+1]) and (words[i] != words[i-1] if i != 0 else True)
    # as before
```

The ternary statement helps for the first iteration of the loop, to avoid comparing the last letter of a string with the first.

Another solution is to use `itertools.groupby` and count the number of instances where a group has a length greater than 1:

```
arr = ['capps','hat','haaah']

from itertools import groupby

res = [sum(1 for _, j in groupby(el) if sum(1 for _ in j) > 1) for el in arr]

print(res)

[1, 0, 1]
```

The `sum(1 for _ in j)` part is used to count the number items in a generator. It's also possible to use `len(list(j))`, though this requires list construction.

Comment: I add this to the for loop
if words[i] == words[i+1] and words[i] !=  words[i-1] doesn't this do the same? It seem like it workd

Comment: What happens when `i = 0`? You get `words[-1]` compared to `words[0]`. But why would you compare the last letter with the first. Remember `-1` counts backwards from the end.

Comment: The reason I ask because when I tried this arr =['ab','aab','abb','abab','abaaaba']
I get [0,0,1,0,1] when adding words[max(0, i-1)]
but when I add words[i-1] I get out put is [0,1,1,0,1] which the right anwser.

And yes, I agree with you. When it i-1 on 0 it goes back works. My question is why it didn't work for this case?

Answer (score 0):

Well, your code counts the number of duplications, so what you observe is quite logical:

- your input is `arr = ['capps','hat','haaah']`
- in 'capps', the letter *p* is duplicated 1 time => myfunc() returns 1
- in 'hat', there is no duplicated letter => myfunc() returns 0
- in 'haaah', the letter *a* is duplicated 2 times => myfunc() returns 2

So finally you get [1,0,2].

For your purpose, I suggest you to use a regex to match and count the number of groups of duplicated letters in each word. I also replaced the usage of `map()` with a list comprehension that I find more readable:

```
import re

def myfunc(words):
    return len(re.findall(r'(\w)\1+', words))

def minimalOperations(arr):
    return [myfunc(a) for a in arr]

arr = ['capps','hat','haaah']
print(minimalOperations(arr))  # [1,0,1]

arr = ['cappsuul','hatppprrrrtyyy','haaah']
print(minimalOperations(arr))  # [2,3,1]
```

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to figure out is when I see a group of three letters how do I make it count as one? I tried to do words[i] == words[i+1] ==words[i+2] as a case. But It response to me string out of range. >.<

Comment: This I can try to see if there's a group of the same three letters for example "aaa" and count it as 1

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of a little more state, specifically if you're looking at duplicates now.

```
def myfunc(words):
    counter = 0 #counters dup letters in words
    seen = None
    len_ = len(words)-1
    for i in range(len_):
        if words[i] == words[i+1] and words[i+1] != seen: #if the letter ahead is the same add one and wasn't the first
            counter+=1
            seen = words[i]
    return counter
```

This gives you the following output

```
>>> arr = ['capps','hat','haaah']
>>> map(myfunc, arr)
[1, 0, 1]
```

As others have pointed out, you could use a regular expression and trade clarity for performance. They key is to find a regular expression that means "two or more repeated characters" and may depend on what you consider to be characters (e.g. how do you treat duplicate punctuation?)

Note: the "regex" used for this is technically an extension on regular expressions because it requires memory.

The form will be `len(re.findall(regex, words))`

Answer (score 0):

I would break this kind of problem into smaller chunks. Starting by grouping duplicates.
[The documentation for itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) has groupby and recipes for this kind of things.

A slightly edited version of `unique_justseen` would look like this:

```
duplicates = (len(sum(1 for _ in group) for _key, group in itertools.groupby("haaah")))
```

and yields values: 1, 3, 1. As soon as any of these values are greater than 1 you have a duplicate. So just count them:

```
sum(n > 1 for n in duplicates)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `re.findall` for matches of 2 or more letters

```
>>> arr = ['capps','hat','haaah']
>>> [len(re.findall(r'(.)\1+', w)) for w in arr]
[1, 0, 1]
```